# Does Key.from_path hit the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a list of key names that I want to bulk fetch 
(the key names are stored in a StringListProperty attached to an entity). 
My general plan was to do:

```
usernames = userrefInstance.users # A collection of strings on another 
model. 
keys = [Key.from_path('User', key_name) for username in usernames] 
users = db.get(keys)
```

My questions does Key.from_path hit the datastore? I am trying to be as 
quick as possible and if Key.from_path hits the data store I need to work 
another way to store a collection of keys - I don't particularly want to 
store the Key object in a list property as I also provide user 
friendly queries across the StringListPropererties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging and questions on another group, it turns out that:

> keys are entirely determined by the app
>   ID and the path, so there's no need to
>   access the datastore for this. -  Nick Johnson

Or you can also use a List of db.Key

Comment: Sure - Put an answer in, I will delete this one and then accept yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you pass to `Key.from_path()` contain all the information necessary to build the unique key so there is no need for it to hit the datastore.

> Each entity in the Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it.
>   The key consists of the following components:
>
> 1. The kind of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Datastore queries
> 2. An identifier for the individual entity, which can be either
>
>    - a key name string
>    - an integer numeric ID
> 3. An optional ancestor path locating the entity within the Datastore hierarchy

source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities